# If a Parseval-frame is orthogonal is it actually a base?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra and $\mathcal{E}$ a Hilbert A-module. If $\{m_j\}$ is a finite Parseval frame for $\mathcal{E}$ and $\{m_j\}$ is orthogonal, is it actually a base? I suspect that's not the case because $\langle m_i,m_i \rangle b=0$ doesn't necessarily imply that $b=0$.

Note: $\{m_j\}$ is a Parseval frame if for all $m\in \mathcal{E}$ we have that 
$$m=\sum_j m_j\langle m_j ,m \rangle$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, by "base" you mean a linearly independent set which spans $\mathcal E$ as a complex vector space.

You are right. Let $A$ be any unital C*-algebra. Consider $A$ as the standard right Hilbert $A$-module. Then $\{1_A\}$ is a frame but clearly not a base, if $A$ has complex dimension greater than one.

Comment: The problem, if I'm not wrong, is that one can also says that "basis" is an orthonormal set with zero orthogonal. If I'm not wrong, the two things do not agree.

Comment: That is true and probably the more useful notion in this setting. Then, my example doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Does it change much if by "base" I mean that the module can be realized as a free $A$-module using $\{m_j\}$?